# Does java.sql.DriverManager support LoginTimeout or not?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

java.sql.DriverManager has setLoginTimeout method, but in the source code I can see that DriverManager only saves timeout in a field but never uses it.

I also tried to connect to a stopped MySQL Windows service with 10 sec timeout

```
DriverManager.setLoginTimeout(10);
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?user=root&password=root");
```

but exception is thrown after one second, timeout is ignored.

What is the correct way to set LoginTimeout or it is not supported at all?

Comment: It 's for maximum not minimum

Answer (score 2):

> but exception is thrown after one second, timeout is ignored.

[`DriverManager#setLoginTimeout(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#setLoginTimeout(int))

> Sets the maximum time in seconds that a driver will wait while
>   attempting to connect to a database.
>
> ***This method set the login timeout used by JDBC drivers.***

This sets the timeout for how long the `Driver` has to wait before the database returns a connection.If you attempt to login and database does not respond within 10 seconds it timeouts.As your service is stopped it immediately gets response as connection can not be established.So,ultimately it waits for database to respond to the login attempt for 10 seconds if it does not get connection it timeouts.

***EDIT***

As I have said above your service is stopped it can detect immediately irrespective of your logIn timeout and throws the `Exception`.

Comment: It is not the `DriverManager` that waits, but the `Driver`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel yes right...

Comment: The important point is that setLoginTimeout has *nothing* to do with why "an exception is thrown after one second".  As Mark Rotteveel and I both said below, "When you attempt to connect to a stopped MySQL server, there is no system listening, and no network connection can be made and this is detected almost immediately."

Answer (score 1):

There are several related factors:

1) DriverManager.setLoginTimeout() (your JDBC driver behavior)

... and ...

2) TCP/IP (your network stack's behavior)

If your turn mySQL "off", then connections to that port (e.g. 3306) will fail *immediately*.  That's what you're seeing.

If you start a service on that port - and you somehow prevent it from responding to connection requests - that's when you'll see the JDBC login timeout.

Answer (score 1):

Your questions are answered by the javadoc of [`setLoginTimeout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#setLoginTimeout-int-) (emphasis mine):

> Sets the **maximum** time in seconds that **a driver** will wait while attempting to connect to a database once the driver has been identified.

The `DriverManager` itself doesn't do anything with the `loginTimeout`. It is up to individual JDBC driver to implement timeout handling and use the value of this property of `DriverManager`. So it is correct that you don't see any use of the value in the `DriverManager` itself. You'd need to check the source of the driver you are using.

The login timeout is is a maximum timeout, that is used for detecting non-responsive systems (eg the network connection is made, but the connection or login handshake stalls). When you attempt to connect to a stopped MySQL server, there is no system listening, and no network connection can be made and this is detected almost immediately.